# Inserting a XML table into a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

I'm trying to put a XML file into a SQL table. I've successfully gotten the XML file into the SQL server using the following code:

```
declare @xmldata as xml

set @xmldata = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'filedestination', SINGLE_BLOB) as X)
```

and the following snippet of code is where I get an error. I'm aware that I must use an INSERT INTO statement but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
INSERT INTO t1(c1, c2, c3)
SELECT  
c1 AS 'c1',
c2 AS 'c2',
c3 as 'c3'
```

I'm currently using SQL Server 2005.

The XML file looks like this

```
<row>
<c1> DATA </c1>
<c2> DATA </c2>
<c3> DATA </c3>
</row>
...
```

Comment: show your error. and where is the dependence between your two queryes?

Comment: Invalid object name 'BenCalCopy1'.

Comment: I don't see `BenCalCopy1` anywhere in your post. You need to tell us what you're doing if we're to help you!

Comment: Sorry, wrong part of my code.

Comment: Invalid object name 't1'

Comment: then you have to define t1 table before inserting into it

Comment: It seems `t1` doesn't exist. What does it have to do with your XML question?

Comment: I've already defined it.

Comment: Alright, so now it gives me Invalid column name 'c1'

Comment: I'm trying to insert the xml into an empty SQL table.

Comment: Where is 'c1' being selected from? You cannot select it out of thin air.

Comment: Might help to show the XML...

Comment: So you need to 1. Post the table creation script. 2. Post the script inserting into it (which would necessarily require the variable `@xmldata` in it). You need to do that or forget about solving your problem in this forum

Comment: I added a portion to include the format of the .xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your last comment you did not address any user directly (e.g.  with `@Shnugo`), so there was no alert. Nobody found your edit obviously...

Don't know if this is still an open issue, but this was an answer:

This is the way you are loading your file

```
declare @xmldata as xml;
set @xmldata = 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'filedestination', SINGLE_BLOB) as X
);
```

Now the variable `@xmldata` should contain XML like you've posted it in your edit. Just for testing I set the variable to some fitting content:

```
SET @xmldata=
'<root>
    <row>
        <c1>DATA1</c1>
        <c2>DATA2</c2>
        <c3>DATA3</c3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <c1>DATA4</c1>
        <c2>DATA5</c2>
        <c3>DATA6</c3>
    </row>
</root>';
```

Now I create a temp table to test the insert

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(c1 VARCHAR(100),c2 VARCHAR(100),c3 VARCHAR(100));
```

And this is the way to insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 
SELECT One.Rw.value('c1[1]','varchar(100)')
      ,One.Rw.value('c2[1]','varchar(100)')
      ,One.Rw.value('c3[1]','varchar(100)')
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/root/row') AS One(Rw);

SELECT * FROM #t1;

GO
DROP TABLE #t1;
```

This was the result:

```
c1      c2      c3
DATA1   DATA2   DATA3
DATA4   DATA5   DATA6
```